# I'm installing paraview from source. I don't have a previous installation but I get a CMake error

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake, paraview

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set
 to NOTFOUND.
 Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake
 files:
 /home/uma/projects/ParaView/VTK/IO/FFMPEG/FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR
    used as include directory in directory
 /home/uma/projects/ParaView/VTK/IO/FFMPEG
 FFMPEG_avcodec_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
     linked by target "vtkIOFFMPEG" in directory
 /home/uma/projects/ParaView/VTK/IO/FFMPEG
 FFMPEG_avformat_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
     linked by target "vtkIOFFMPEG" in directory
 /home/uma/projects/ParaView/VTK/IO/FFMPEG
 FFMPEG_avutil_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
     linked by target "vtkIOFFMPEG" in directory
 /home/uma/projects/ParaView/VTK/IO/FFMPEG
 FFMPEG_swscale_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
     linked by target "vtkIOFFMPEG" in directory
 /home/uma/projects/ParaView/VTK/IO/FFMPEG

I have all the required libraries installed. I followed http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Build_And_Install instructions for installing paraview. ccmake $HOME/projects/ParaView4 from ParaView-bin gave me the error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've turned on `PARAVIEW_ENABLE_FFMPEG` but you don't have FFMPEG development modules installed or locatable by CMake. Either installed FFMPEG or turn off `PARAVIEW_ENABLE_FFMPEG` using `ccmake` or `cmake-gui`.

Comment: Thanks; I oned FFMPEG and I installed and built FFMPEG with these instructions->https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu . I don't know why I'm getting the error. How can I set these variables, if I should set these seperately?